# Compare a file with two separate lookup files using awk

Tags: shell, awk

Basically, I want to check if strings present in lookup_1 & lookup_2 exists in my xyz.txt file then perform action & redirect output to an output file. Also, my code is currently substituting all occurrences of the strings in lookup_1 even as substring, but I need it to only substitute if there's a whole word match.
Can you please help in tweaking the code to achieve the same?

**code**

```
awk '
FNR==NR { if ($0 in lookups)    
             next                            
          lookups[$0]=$0
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {         
              oldstr=$i
              newstr=""
              while (oldstr) {               
                    len=length(oldstr)
                    newstr=newstr substr(oldstr,1,1) substr("##",1,len-1)
                    oldstr=substr(oldstr,4)   
              }
              ndx=index(lookups[$0],$i)   
              lookups[$0]=substr(lookups[$0],1,ndx-1) newstr substr(lookups[$0],ndx+length($i))
          }
          next
        }

        { for (i in lookups) { 
              ndx=index($0,i)                
              while (ndx > 0) {                       t
                    $0=substr($0,1,ndx-1) lookups[i] substr($0,ndx+length(lookups[i]))
                    ndx=index($0,i)                    
              }
          }
          print
        }
' lookup_1 xyz.txt > output.txt
```

**lookup_1**

```
ha
achine
skhatw
at
ree
ter
man
dun
```

**lookup_2**

```
United States
CDEXX123X
Institution
```

**xyz.txt**

```
[1] [hamilton] This is a demo file
Demo file is currently being reviewed by user ter
[2] [ter] This is a demo file 
Demo file is currently being edited by user skhatw
Internal Machine's Change Request being processed. Approved by user mandeep
Institution code is 'CDEXX123X' where country is United States
```

**current output**

```
[1] [h#milton] This is a demo file
Demo file is currently being reviewed by user t##
[2] [t##] This is a demo file 
Demo file is currently being edited by user skh#tw
Internal Ma##i##'s Ch#nge Request being processed. Approved by user m##deep
Institution code is 'CDEXX123X' where country is United States
```

**desired output**

```
[1] [hamilton] This is a demo file
Demo file is currently being reviewed by user t##
[2] [t##] This is a demo file 
Demo file is currently being edited by user s##a##
Internal Machine's Change Request being processed. Approved by user mandeep
I##t##u##o# code is 'C##X##2##' where country is U##t## S##t##
```

Comment: Can you add  a [minimal reproducable examle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please have a look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a couple changes to the current code:

- feed the results of `cat lookup_1 lookup_2` into `awk` such that it looks like a single file to `awk` (see last line of new code)
- use word boundary flags (`\<` and `\>`) to build regexes with which to perform the replacements (see 2nd half of new code)

The new code:

```
awk '
        # the FNR==NR block of code remains the same

FNR==NR { if ($0 in lookups)
             next
          lookups[$0]=$0
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
              oldstr=$i
              newstr=""
              while (oldstr) {
                    len=length(oldstr)
                    newstr=newstr substr(oldstr,1,1) substr("##",1,len-1)
                    oldstr=substr(oldstr,4)
              }
              ndx=index(lookups[$0],$i)
              lookups[$0]=substr(lookups[$0],1,ndx-1) newstr substr(lookups[$0],ndx+length($i))
          }
          next
        }

        # complete rewrite of the following block to perform replacements based on a regex using word boundaries

        { for (i in lookups) {
              regex= "\\<" i "\\>"            # build regex
              gsub(regex,lookups[i])          # replace strings that match regex
          }
          print
        }
' <(cat lookup_1 lookup_2) xyz.txt            # combine lookup_1/lookup_2 into a single stream so both files are processed under the FNR==NR block of code
```

This generates:

```
[1] [hamilton] This is a demo file
Demo file is currently being reviewed by user t##
[2] [t##] This is a demo file
Demo file is currently being edited by user s##a##
Internal Machine's Change Request being processed. Approved by user mandeep
I##t##u##o# code is 'C##X##2##' where country is U##t## S##t##
```

**NOTES:**

- the 'boundary' characters (`\<` and `\>`) match on non-word characters; in `awk` a word is defined as a sequence of numbers, letters and underscores; see [GNU awk - regex operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) for more details
- all of the sample lookup values fall within the definition of an `awk` word so this new code works as desired
- your previous question includes lookup values that cannot be considered as an `awk` 'word' (eg, `@vanti Finserv Co.`, `11:11 - Capital`, `MS&CO(NY)`) in which case this new code may fail to replace these new lookup values
- for lookup values that contain non-word characters it's not clear how you would define *'whole word match'* as you would also need to determine when a non-word character (eg, `@`) is to be treated as part of a lookup string vs being treated as a word boundary

---

If you need to replace lookup values that contain (`awk`) non-word characters you could try replacing the word-boundary characters with `\W`, though this then causes problems for the lookup values that are (`awk`) 'words'.

One possible workaround may be to run a dual set of regex matches for each lookup value, eg:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { ... no changes to this block of code ... }

        { for (i in lookups) {
              regex= "\\<" i "\\>"
              gsub(regex,lookups[i])
              regex= "\\W" i "\\W"
              gsub(regex,lookups[i])
          }
          print
        }
' <(cat lookup_1 lookup_2) xyz.txt
```

You'll need to determine if the 2nd regex breaks your *'whole word match'* requirement.